# Extracting the entire text content from an HTML document using Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I am using the following code snippet to extract the entire text content from an HTML document, using Jsoup:

```
String text = doc.body().text();
System.out.println(text);
```

It does work but unfortunately all the text content is a single line, with no linebreaks.  If I redirect the output to a text file, the text file has just one inordinately long line.

---

**Question:** What is the correct way to extract the entire text content from an HTML document such that when the text content is written to a file, it is properly newlined, as needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wholeText()` to keep the line breaks in the text:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("YourWebPage").get();
String textWithLines = Jsoup.parse(doc.html()).wholeText();
System.out.println(textWithLines);
```